# How to open the initial window in tkinter again?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a following question. I want to make a button in tkinter that will delete existing changes and the window will looks like the initial window.
This is my initial Window 1:

[image]

This is how the window looks like when I click on the first two buttons, Window 2:

[image]

Now I would like to click on the "Zpět" button and I want to see Window 1 again.
Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
home_frame = tk.Frame(root)
home_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

def raise_new_payment():
    tk.Label(text=f"Stav bilance k 2021-09-09").grid()


def back():
    """I would like to this function to clean everything."""
    tk.Label().destroy()

platba = tk.Button(
    home_frame,
    text="Zadej novou platbu",
    command=lambda: raise_new_payment(),
)
platba.pack(pady=10)

zpet = tk.Button(
    home_frame,
    text="Zpět",
    command=back,
)
zpet.pack(pady=10)
```

I don't know how to use the `back()` function. I tried to delete the tk.Label as created in `raise_new_payment()`, but it did not work.  Can you help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `home_frame` is inside `root.grid_slaves()`. So you are destroying it and then trying to call `home_frame.tkraise()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks a lot for your help. But I still need a small one :) I have edited my question, can you have a look on it, please?

Comment: Right now you create a new `home_frame` variable but never call `.pack` on that new frame. Also wouldn't it be better to just use `zpet.destroy()` instead of everything that you have inside `back`?

Comment: @TheLizzard 1) I call `platba.pack(pady=10) ` inside the back() function
2) I tried to use `destroy` function (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python), but it closed the button or the whole window. Which is not, what I need. I need to "clean" the window and return to Window 1.

Comment: The only difference between the two images is the label at the bottom of the window, so why don't you just destroy that label inside `back()`?

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your answer. Yes, to destroy the label is what I want. But how can I destroy it inside `back` ? I tried `tk.Label().destroy()` inside `back`, but it doesn`t work..

Comment: There is nothing in your code related to that label, so how can I answer your question?

Comment: @acw1668 sorry, I just updated my question. Is there enough information to help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create the label once and don't call `.pack()` on it first, i.e. it is not visible initially.

Then update it inside `raise_new_payment()` and call `.pack()` to show it.

You can call `.pack_forget()` to hide it again inside `back()`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
home_frame = tk.Frame(root)
home_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

def raise_new_payment():
    # update label and show it
    lbl.config(text=f"Stav bilance k 2021-09-09")
    lbl.pack()

def back():
    # hide the label
    lbl.pack_forget()

platba = tk.Button(
    home_frame,
    text="Zadej novou platbu",
    command=lambda: raise_new_payment(),
)
platba.pack(pady=10)

zpet = tk.Button(
    home_frame,
    text="Zpět",
    command=back,
)
zpet.pack(pady=10)

# create the label and initially hide it
lbl = tk.Label(home_frame)

root.mainloop()
```